# Why does a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{Q}$ have either 1 element or infinitely many elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Why does a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{Q}$ have either 1 element or infinitely many elements?

Can anyone help me with the answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every vector space is non-empty (exactly one of the axioms implies this -- which one?). If the vector space has one element, then we are done ($\{0\}$ is a vector space). Now suppose it had one non-zero element, $a$. Since vector spaces are closed under scalar multiplication, it must contain $\lambda a$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb F$ (where $\mathbb F$ is $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, or $\mathbb Q$). The $\lambda a$ are all distinct (since the multiplicative identity is unique), giving us infinitely many elements.

Comment: Do you mean "at least one non-zero element"? As you yourself point out, it already has at least one element, there's no need to suppose so.

Comment: I suppose so, but I was aiming to give a more logical walk-through than a formal proof. Intuitively, I thought *I'll give myself a "generator" and do casework*

Comment: Then it'd be more concise to just phrase it like this: *If the vector space has exactly one element, then we're done. Otherwise, it has at least one non-zero element $a$...*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The existence of such a vector space is, of course, trivial.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think the crux of the question is why all the $\lambda a$ are distinct (when $a\ne 0$).  I don't see how this follows from the multiplicative identity (of the field, I guess you mean?) being unique.

Comment: Suppose $\lambda_1 a = \lambda_2 a$, where the $\lambda$ are non-zero. Then $a = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} a$, implying $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$. Thus if $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, $\lambda_1 a \neq \lambda_2 a$

Comment: Why does $a = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} a$ imply $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$?  How do you divide by $a$?  (If $a$ were a scalar, you'd do this by multiplying by its inverse; but $a$ is not a scalar.)

Comment: I multiplied both sides by $\lambda_1^{-1}$. Also, $v = \lambda v$ implies $\lambda = 1$ ($v = \lambda v \Rightarrow 1v = \lambda v \Rightarrow (1- \lambda) v = 0 \Rightarrow 1 - \lambda = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda = 1$) Why so keen on grilling me? This stuff is in chapter 1 of a high school linear algebra book

Comment: My reasoning for "multiplicative identity is unique" is because $\lambda = 1$ is the unique element such that $v = \lambda v$.